# How do I search content on a specific subreddit on Reddit.com?

Tags: reddit

For instance, I want to search all "game" in https://www.reddit.com/r/france/ how can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Old Reddit

1. Find the search field on the page (it's in the top right)
2. Enable the check box **limit my search to r/france**
3. Type your search term
4. Hit enter

[image: Picture Example, select "limit my search to r/france]

Following these steps you would get to a page like this:
https://www.reddit.com/r/france/search?q=game&restrict_sr=on&sort=relevance&t=all

You can see from the URL, it's part of the /france subreddit, "restrict" to subreddit is enabled and the search term is "game".

If you do not want to use the reddit built-in search, you can also type this into Google:

```
game site:reddit.com/r/france
```

This will make you search the /france subreddit for the term "game".

### New Reddit

- You can search anything in the top search bar. The results page will show results for all of reddit. But, if you are visiting a subreddit there will be an option on the results page to filter to only from that subreddit.
  [image]
- `https://www.reddit.com/r/SUBREDDIT/search/?q=test%20query&source=recent&restrict_sr=1`

Relevant URL GET Params

- q = query
- restrict_sr = whether restrict to subreddit

Comment: What am I missing here? Why don't I have that checkbox? Is this answer now outdated? If so, other than the google solution, how is it accomplished now? Is it browser-dependent?

Comment: Answer is still up to date, confirmed working for Chrome & Firefox latest versions. If you cannot see the checkbox right away, try clicking into the search field or typing any character. It will then extend downwards to reveal the box.

Comment: I just updated Chrome and Firefox and according to the App Store, Safari is up to date. I still do not get that checkbox. Clicking in the search field does show a drop-down, but contains no checkboxes - only prior searches and trending. Apparently, if I go to r/whatever, the search defaults to only that sub-reddit and the results have a link at the top to "search all of reddit". is the checkbox a windows thing?

Comment: @hepcat72 Updated the answer with info about how it works in the new reddit view. Once it's approved you should see it.

Comment: there is no search in the top right

Comment: What a dumb redesign decision

Comment: I found that I must run a search, wait for the result page to load, then click an available button/link to search only the subreddit I had visited. Inefficient and hard to find (only found it via this SE answer). IMO the option should be in the drop-down on search.

Comment: I guess "new" has become "old", I don't see any such search bar. I see one on the right below the header and it will search all of reddit but if you click in it a checkbox to restrict the search to the current subreddit will appear.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy & paste this `URL` in your `browser`'s address bar & replace the values within the angle brackets with your specific search needs:

```
https://www.reddit.com/r/<enter-subreddit>/search?q=<enter-search-keyword>&restrict_sr=on.
```

Answer (score 0):

In the new version of Reddit, if you intend to look for something in a subreddit, first you may want to begin your search with "r/XXX" (XXX is the name of a subreddit) in the search bar, and then click on the subreddit from automatically recommended results below the bar. Finally, you will enter the subreddit you're interested in and begin your search now. It might be more straightforward than constructing a URL.

[image: Example for Searching in a Subreddit]